# How to take foreign key in Oracle SQL DEV

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I set two tables in my db. one is  a users table (each users has an ID) and a second is event's table (each event has it's id) now I want to create a thired table with a userID and eventId in order to know who is the event administrator of each event.

At the moment I have already created the thired table with the 2 objects.
but I dont know how to releat the cells to thier main tables.

Comment: Consider creating a view on both the tables. But, you need to explain more about the structure of the two tables. What is the key to join these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

may be
you 3 table

```
create thired_table(
id number(10), -- PK
id_user number(10), --FK on table user
id_event number(10) --FK on table event
);
```

your select

```
select u.user_name, e.events
  from user u
    join thired_table t on t.id_user = u.id
    join event e on e.id = t.id_event
```